# Under what circumstances is ref_view{E} ill-formed and subrange{E} not?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3, std-ranges

C++20 introduces [`views::all`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/all_view) which is a range adaptor that returns a `view` that includes all elements of its range argument.

The expression `views::all(E)` is expression-equivalent (has the same effect) to:

- `decay-copy(E)` if the decayed type of `E` models `view`.
- Otherwise, `ref_view{E}` if that expression is well-formed
- Otherwise, `subrange{E}`

The first case represents that a [`view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view)'s type is not changed after being piped with `views::all` ([goldbot](https://godbolt.org/z/5vYadrEY6)):

```
auto r = views::iota(0);
static_assert(std::same_as<decltype(r), decltype(r | views::all)>);
```

The second case is used to wrap a [`viewable_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/viewable_range) with `ref_view` to facilitate range pipe operations:

```
int r[] = {0, 1, 2};
static_assert(std::same_as<ranges::ref_view<int[3]>, decltype(r | views::all)>);
```

But regarding the third case, I can't think of under what circumstances `subrange{E}` is well-formed and `ref_view{E}` is ill-formed.

What is its purpose? Can someone give an example of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But regarding the third case, I can't think of under what circumstances `subrange{E}` is well-formed and `ref_view{E}` is ill-formed.

`ref_view{E}` is only well-formed for lvalue ranges.

`subrange{E}` is only well-formed for borrowed ranges. You can find its deduction guide in [[range.subrange.general]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.subrange.general):

```cpp
template<borrowed_­range R>
  subrange(R&&) ->
    subrange<iterator_t<R>, sentinel_t<R>,
             (sized_­range<R> || sized_­sentinel_­for<sentinel_t<R>, iterator_t<R>>)
               ? subrange_kind::sized : subrange_kind::unsized>;
```

Where a borrowed range is either an lvalue again or a range that opts into being borrowed from. Types like `string_view` and `span` are borrowed, for instance.

So if you have something like an rvalue `vector<int>`, then that's not a view (first bullet) nor can you construct a `ref_view` from it (because it's an rvalue), nor can you construct a `subrange` from it (because it's a non-borrowed range).

---

I realize this doesn't quite answer the question cause I flipped the polarity in my head while typing the answer. But [T.C.'s got me covered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67471325/2069064).

Another purely hypothetical example is a non-view range that stores its contents in a `shared_ptr`, and then its iterators also share that data. Something like:

```cpp
struct SharedVector {
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> data;

    struct Iterator {
        std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> data;
        std::vector<int>::iterator cur;

        // ...
    };

    auto begin() -> Iterator { return {data, data->begin()}; }
    auto end() -> Iterator { return {data, data->end()}; }
};
```

An rvalue `SharedVector` would not be a view (not `O(1)`-destructible), you could not `ref_view{E}` it (because it's an rvalue), but such a range could still be borrowed, so `subrange{E}` could work.

Comment: Why does a view require O(1)-destructible?

Comment: @xskxzr This is a good question with an [involved answer](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2415r0.html)

Comment: It is in fact https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3452. The issue does not specify why a view should be O(1)-destructible. Maybe the reason is the same as that mentioned in P2415 (to make passing-by-value cheap) but that does not convince me---"cheap" does not mean "O(1)".

Answer (score 4):

Borrowed rvalue non-view ranges (views would fall under the first bullet so that the question doesn't arise).

The canonical example in the current standard is `span` of nonzero static extent (like `span<int, 42>`). A hypothetical borrowed range type that doesn't support assignment would be another example. Synthetic examples can be constructed as well (since both `borrowed_range` and `view` are opt-in).

Comment: Note since [P2325](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2325r3.html) `std::span` becomes a view.

Comment: Is there any practical use of a borrowed range type that doesn't support assignment?

Answer (score 2):

```
template<__NotSameAs<ref_view> T>
requires std::convertible_to<T, R&> && requires { _FUN(std::declval<T>()); }
constexpr ref_view(T&& t);
```

from this, rvalues seem iffy.

```
template<class R>
ref_view(R&) -> ref_view<R>;
```

also looks like it blocks rvalues.

Make an rvalue that you can `subrange{E}`.  Like a subrange rvalue.  Probably others, depending on deduction guides of subrange.

Comment: I think in that case, `E` is a `viewable_range` which is an rvalue and not a `view`, but I cannot find such `E` that makes the return type of `E | std::views::all` a `subrange`.

Comment: I think the `E` can be `std::span<int, 3>{v}`. https://godbolt.org/z/v6o84q111. But this can be improved by Barry's [P2325R0](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2021/p2325r0.html).